# generic in an interface in java

Tags: java, generics, interface

Say I have this interface (which is NOT parameterised)

```
public interface MyInterface
{
     MyInterface copy();
}
```

How do I make sure any implementation of `copy` would return the actual subtype (and not `MyInterface`).

Eg.,

```
public Impl implements MyInterface
{
    @Override
    public Impl copy() <<<<< The returns type of this needs to be 'Impl'
    {
        return new Impl();
    }
}
```

But I can't prevent any implementation to do this:

```
public Foo implements MyInterface
{
    @Override
    public MyInterface copy() <<<<< The returns type of this needs to be 'Foo'
    {
        return new Impl();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to worry about the reference of the return type. It's the actual object that will do everything as per [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism).

Comment: In the calling code you can cast the return value from Foo.copy() to a Foo but you need to be sure then that you're calling copy on a Foo in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a generic type which is a subclass of the interface:

```
interface MyInterface<T extends MyInterface<T>> {
    T copy();
}


class Foo implements MyInterface<Foo> {
    public Foo copy() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to parameterize my `MyInterface` because it doesn't make any mean anything when put in the context.

Comment: Don't ignore the warnings *MyInterface is a raw type. References to generic type MyInterface<T> should be parameterized* It's not generic inside `T extends MyInterface`

Answer (score 0):

> Say I have this interface **(which is NOT parameterised)**

If you want to keep it non-parameterized, there is no solution that will satisfy both your examples. And I don't see why you would want to if you're programming to interfaces and don't control the implementations of your interface.